# Is there a way to change comma to underscore within a quoted field (delimiter = ,)

Tags: awk

I have a csv file. There are fields within this csv file containing quotes. And within these quotes there could be commas available, this is not always the case. If I extract a column using:

```
awk -F, '{ print $3 }' testfile.csv
```

This won't work. So my idea is to change the , within the quoted field to _ and 'escape' the problem.

This is the contents of my file:

```
chromosome,position,marker,sample1,sample2
chr1,100,NA,A,C
chr1,200,"test1,test2",A,C
chr1,300,NA,A,C
chr1,400,"test6",A,C
chr1,500,NA,A,C
chr1,600,"test3,test4,test5",A,C
```

My desired contents would be:

```
chromosome,position,marker,sample1,sample2
chr1,100,NA,A,C
chr1,200,"test1_test2",A,C
chr1,300,NA,A,C
chr1,400,"test6",A,C
chr1,500,NA,A,C
chr1,600,"test3_test4_test5",A,C
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to replace `,` by `_` in quoted strings or do you need to extract the third column from your CSV file ? In the latter case, I would use [python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead of awk

Comment: I'd like to have the entire row, not the third column

Comment: In the former case, I would split lines with `"` as field separator and replace `,` by `_` only in even columns.

Comment: Your awk command does not output the entire row, only the third column

Comment: This I know (of course :) ) but this was to visualize that problem with the commas within quotes.

Comment: I think this is enough "awk '{gsub(/,test/,"_test")}1' file"